# Define a function in Vim which is one time use only (without editing of .vimrc)

Tags: vim

I was wondering if there is a way to define a very simple function without editing .vimrc.
For instance I need a very simple function once and will probably not use it again anytime soon :

```
function Func()
    :%s/bmp/png/g
    :w
    :next
endfunction
```

Where in the currently opened vim instance can I define it so it's wiped away once I'm done ?
Or maybe should I use something else than function for this kind of use ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You might consider something like `:bufdo %s/bmp/png/g|w` instead; this will execute the substitution command and the write command for each buffer in the buffer list, making it unnecessary to define a function that needs to be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function` is a command; it's not a special syntax usable only in `.vimrc`.

If you type `:function Func()` in a `vim` session, you will start the definition. After you hit enter, you'll be prompted with a `:` for the next line of the function, which you can abbreviate as `%s/bar/png` (the leading `:` is not necessary). You will continue to be prompted for the next line of the function definition until you enter `endfunction`, at which point the execution of `function` is complete.

Then you can call the function with `:call Func()` as usual.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the tips ! That will totally help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Copy the function to the clipboard and run:

```
:@+ Enter
```

I suggest adding a map to call the function:

```
function Func()
    :%s/bmp/png/g
    :w
    :next
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>s call Func()<CR>
```

Of course, the key combination is your choice!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `bufdo` solves the XY part of this problem

```
bufdo %s/.../.../g | write
```

Comment: Oh yes of course, it was not much about the function itself than the way to define it on the go instead of going thought .vimrc